# СПП с придаточным цели?

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор

Ум даден для того, чтобы облегчить жизнь и путь человеческий на земле.

Союз чтобы, указательное слово в главной части ТОГО. СПП расчлененной структуры, придаточное цели. Верно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это СПП с придаточным цели. Правда, *для того чтобы* — это сложный союз, состоящих из нескольких слов, а указальных слов (о которых вы сказали) нет.

Comment: А не СПП разве?

Comment: Ой, это опечтка. Верно вы сказали. Ответ обновил.